# Why the SELECT query not get the data into application item?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to SELECT the beds into POPUP LOV depends on the ward selected on another POPUP LOV

I used this in list of value SQL query to SELECT the beds :

```
select b.bed_no
from hospital_beds b , hospital_wards w
where bed_status = 1
and b.ward_no = w.ward_no
and w.ward_foriegn_name like '%:P22_WARD_NO%'
and b.hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
```

but when I select the ward name then go to beds POPUP its not get the beds

when I run the QUERY in SQL command its returning data

this is the SELECT I used in SQL to test its working or not and its working :

```
select b.bed_no
from hospital_beds b , hospital_wards w
where bed_status = 1
and b.ward_no = w.ward_no
and w.ward_foriegn_name like '%male medical%'
and b.hospital_no = 720022;
```

whats the wrong with my query ?

EDIT :
I changed the SQL QUERY :

```
select b.bed_no as display , bed_no as return 
from hospital_beds b , hospital_wards w
where bed_status = 1
and b.ward_no = w.ward_no
and w.ward_foriegn_name like '%' || :P22_WARD_NO || '%'
and b.hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
```

[image]

then when run the form and select the ward from the list and try to select the beds no bed appear what is the missing please ?

[image]

I tried in Parent items the following :

```
1- P22_WARD_NO - no beds show
2- P22_WARD_NO , P0_HOSPITAL_NO - no beds show 
3- P22_WARD_NO  , P22_BED_NO - no beds show
```

in items to submit I tried :

```
1- P22_BED_NO  - no beds show 
2- empty - no beds show
```

where is the missing ?

I want to create a hospital system

the tables DDL :

```
     CREATE TABLE "HOSPITAL_WARDS" 
       (    "HOSPITAL_NO" VARCHAR2(10), 
        "WARD_NO" VARCHAR2(6), 
        "WARD_NATIVE_NAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "WARD_FORIEGN_NAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "HOSPITAL_WARDS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("WARD_NO")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
       ) ;
    
     CREATE TABLE "HOSPITAL_BEDS" 
       (    "HOSPITAL_NO" VARCHAR2(10), 
        "WARD_NO" VARCHAR2(6), 
        "BED_NO" VARCHAR2(8), 
        "BED_STATUS" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "BED_TYPE" NUMBER(6,0), 
        CONSTRAINT "HOSPITAL_BEDS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("BED_NO")
      USING INDEX  ENABLE
       ) ;
    
      ALTER TABLE "HOSPITAL_BEDS" ADD CONSTRAINT "HOSPITAL_BEDS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("WARD_NO")
          REFERENCES "HOSPITAL_WARDS" ("WARD_NO") ENABLE;
```

P0_HOSPITAL_NO the global variable login hospital because the system will be more than one hospital so I keep the hospital number which logged in like multi branch company the system multi hospitals .

this is sample of the data

```
table HOSPITAL_WARDS
hospital no    ward no       ward f.name              ward n.name 
100              1            male medical ward           جناح باطنة رجال
100               2           male surgical ward           جناح جراحة رجال 

table HOSPITAL_BEDS 
hospital no    ward no   bed no    bed status  
  100            1         1       (1)  Available 
  100            1         2       (1) Available 
  100            1         3       (2) Not available

  100            2         1        (1) available
  100            2         2        (1) available
  100            2         3        (1) available
```

Then I have 2 list of values SQL QUERY the first one for hospital admission wards

```
select  CASE WHEN APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_LANG = 'ar-ae'  
THEN WARD_NATIVE_NAME  
ELSE WARD_FORIEGN_NAME END as ward_DESC,
    ward_NO as ward_no 
 from HOSPITAL_WARDS
 where hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO
```

the second list of values to read the available beds for selected admission wards in the item ward

```
select b.bed_no as display , b.bed_no as return 
from hospital_beds b , hospital_wards w
where bed_status = 1
and b.ward_no = w.ward_no
and w.ward_foriegn_name like '%' || :P22_WARD_NO || '%'
and b.hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
```

I removed P22_BED_NO  from cascading list of values and kept only P22_WARD_NO  on parent item for P22_BED_NO  page item ,
this is the full cycle thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three objections:

- did you set **Parent LoV** property to both items you're using in this `WHERE` clause? If not, do so (image illustrates it, as you commented that you don't know where that property is)

  [image]
- did you try to concatenate the first one with wildcards, i.e.

  ```
  and w.ward_foriegn_name like '%' || :P22_WARD_NO || '%'
  and b.hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
  ```
- query you posted is invalid if we speak of Apex LoV queries; they are supposed to return **two values**: display and return value. The first one is usually some *name*, and the second one is usually some *id*

---

**[EDIT, based on additional info you posted]**

The second LoV query seems to be invalid. You shouldn't match `ward_no` to their **name**. Try this instead:

```
select b.bed_no d, b.bed_No r
from hospital_beds b join hospital_wards w on w.ward_no = b.ward_no
where b.bed_status = 1
  and w.ward_no = :P22_WARD_NO
  and b.hospital_no = :P0_HOSPITAL_NO;
```

Of course, put both P22_WARD_NO and P0_HOSPITAL_NO into "Parent items" property.

Comment: first point I didnt set the Parent LOV how to set it ?                                                                 About second point I tried the concatenation and its get all the beds in all wards not only the beds in the selected ward                                                                                                           About the third point I have more than 60 LOV and I used it as you said with display and return value but this case different no display name I need to select the bed number direct which is the return value also , second poit need some updates thank you

Comment: **1)** I added a screenshot which shows it. **2)** you got all beds because P22_WARD_NO wasn't in *session state* and it was presumed to be NULL. Once you put both items into "Parent Item(s)" property, filter should work. **3)** It doesn't matter that you need only bed number; query **must** have two values, so select it twice: `select bed_no as display_value, bed_no as return_value from ...`

Comment: I updated the question can you please check it , I tried everything but still not show the beds thank you

Comment: Remove P22_BED_NO from "Items to Submit", it doesn't make any sense as you're returning value into it. Are you sure that P22_WARD_NO contains correct data? What is its query? And what is P0_HOSPITAL_NO's value? Could you post several sample rows for both HOSPITAL_BEDS and HOSPITAL_WARDS tables so that we could test it ourselves?

Comment: I posted the full details thank you for your time

Comment: thank you so much its working now :) I need your help a lot of times coming days and weeks because I am new to apex and I have to make this system